# How to split a string into single values in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I currently have the string `'animal'` and I want to be able to split it for the value of `'a,n,i,m,a,l'` while using an excel formula.

Comment: What is your end goal?

Comment: To take any value that the formula is given and have it be split with a , 
So 'pet' -> p,e,t etc

Comment: And should it be comma-delimited in one new cell?

Comment: yes that is the end goal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to the dynamic array formula SEQUENCE:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",,MID(A1,SEQUENCE(LEN(A1)),1))
```

[image]